# checking assumptions with a residual plot

Tags: statistics, regression

As a part of a task I took a regression equation $y(x)$ for a certain sample (1) and used it with the $x$ values of a different sample (2) to produce a residual plot as shown, for residual-regression value
[image]
Next I need to determine whether the regression model is still applicable for sample (2).

I use 2 different approaches to determine it,

1. I calculate the regression model for sample 2 and compare it to the regression model of sample 1, if the coefficients are different for the two, I determine it to be non-applicable.

2.The residuals need to be distributed with a constant variance, so if I get a slope in my trendline, as shown here, I determine it to be non-applicable as a result of a non-constant variance.

Are these two approaches in fact correct?

Comment: You're on the right track thinking about the slope of the trendline, but constant variance has to do with heteroskedasticity, it doesn't necessarily have to do with the slope of the trendline. But, you could test the null hypothesis that the slope of the regression in your second residual plot is 0, that would test whether the first model fits the second sample. The problem with heteroskedasticity is that your standard error will be affected by it, but you could use the robust sandwich standard error estimator to deal with that.

Comment: thank you, is the first approach correct?

Comment: The first approach could work, but you'd need to do a hypothesis test, not just look at the slope estimates directly. It would be like a t-test for difference of means, where you need to account for both standard errors and sample sizes as well.

Comment: how you recommend to approach the problem?

Comment: If I had all the data, I would run a single regression with both samples aggregated, use a dummy variable to denote the two different samples, interact that dummy with the slope, and test whether the coefficient on the interaction term is significant. Without the data, I'd just test the slope of the linear model through the residuals and see if it's significantly different from 0.

Answer (score 1):

The model has several parts.
First, what you are saying about the residuals having constant variance is part of the model, but the argument you are making is that the residuals do not have mean 0. That is a different assumption in the model. Another assumption is that the residuals are normally distributed. These are 3 different assumptions built into the statement that the residuals are iid normal with mean 0 and constant variance.
The test for whether the estimated slope in sample 1 is the same as that in sample 2 is fine by finding the difference in the two estimates and dividing by the square root of the sum of the two standard errors squared. Since the two estimates are independent and approximately normal, this is standard normal if the two have the same slope.
If you want to test whether the slope in sample 2 is equal to some fixed value, that is something else. Subtract the fixed value from the estimate and divide by the s.e.